# Idiomatic Scala - Performing Functions on Tuple Values

Tags: scala, collections, dictionary, tuples

Folks,
  I've got the following map and structural type defined:

```
type Mergeable = { def mergeFrom(data: Array[Byte]): com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite }
  val dispatchMap = Map(
    1 -> (ZombieSighting.defaultInstance.asInstanceOf[Mergeable], "akka://UlyssesAgenda/user/ServerCore/DispatchTarget")
  )
```

Basically what I'm doing is defining a map that says "when I read protobuf message type 1 off the wire, create a ZombieSighting from the bytes, and dispatch that to the actor found at the indicated string".

So, this is the code I have today that creates a message, an actor, and sends the message to the actor:

```
val dispatchInfo = dispatchMap.get(messageType)
val theMessage = dispatchInfo.map { _._1.mergeFrom(theBytes) }.get
val actorPath = dispatchInfo.map { _._2 } 
val targetActor = actorPath.map { SocketServer.system.actorFor(_) }
targetActor.map { _ ! theMessage }
```

When I look at this, all I can think of is how many lines of non-functional programming this looks like and I can't help but think there's a much more elegant way to do this. I know I can write functions that take tuples as parameters and return modified tuples, but I don't think that buys me anything in terms of clean idiomatic scala here.

My gut instinct says there's a single map statement I can run on "dispatchMap.get(messageType)" that will give me an instance of an Akka actor based on tuple._2 and a merged protobuf object based on tuple._1.

Can someone suggest a way to pimp this code and reduce the number of lines and make it more functional? e.g.

```
val (targetActor, theMessage) = ????
targetActor ! theMessage
```

Edit: here's my first attempt at a refactor.. Is this the "Scala way" to do it?

```
val (msg, actor) = dispatchMap.get(messageType).map {
    case (m:Mergeable, path:String) => 
        (m.mergeFrom(theBytes), SocketServer.system.actorFor(path) )
}.get
actor ! msg
```

Edit 2: Here's a version suggested by the commenter below, but I don't know if this is really idiomatic or not:

```
  def dispatchMessage: IO.Iteratee[Unit] =
    repeat {
    for {
        (messageType, byteString) <- readMessage
    } yield {
        for (
            (protoMessage, actorPath) <- dispatchMap.get(messageType);
            theMessage = protoMessage.mergeFrom(byteString.toArray);
            targetActor = SocketServer.system.actorFor(actorPath) )
        yield 
            targetActor ! theMessage
    }
}
```

?

Comment: Basically, without knowing the types, it's nearly impossible to diagnose the failure. The compiler diagnostics might help, but you've not included them, either. Perhaps someone who's familiar with Protocol Buffers might be able to figure it out.

Comment: My problem isn't with protocol buffers. My problem was only with figuring out how to get useful information out of my dispatchMap object in a Scala-ish way. I have all the protobuf stuff figured out.

Comment: Sure, but without a mass of details that originate in Protocol Buffers it's impossible to interpret or analyze your code. Also... What is `repeat`?

Comment: Sorry I didn't include a pile of extra details.. I didn't want to confuse the issue. My only question was how to optimize a map comprehension and didn't think folks would need the gory details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code might be written like this:

```
val akkaResponseFuture =
  for ((bytes, actorPath) <- dispatchMap.get(messageType);
       theMessage         <- bytes.mergeFrom(theBytes);
       targetActor        =  SocketServer.system.actorFor(actorPath))
  yield
    targetActor ! theMessage
```

This may very well not be right. I did it without trying to create working code, since your sample is not self-contained. Also, `theBytes` is nowhere defined.

But I'm pretty sure you can use a for comprehension to clarify and streamline it.

Comment: @KevinHoffman: No offense, but your original question is hard enough to read, but multi-line code in a comment is impossible. Would you amend your question with this response?

Comment: I've spent the past 5 minutes trying to figure out how to get code into a comment.. I'll edit the original :)